# Angle Bisector Theorem (2)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> We have a $\triangle ABC$ with $\angle ACB=120^\circ$. $CL$ and $AT$ are angle bisectors, $L\in AB$ and $T\in BC$. I should show that $LT$ is the angle bisector of $\angle CLB$.
>   [image]

By the angle bisector theorem, $\dfrac{AL}{LB}=\dfrac{AC}{BC}$ and $\dfrac{CT}{TB}=\dfrac{AC}{AB}$. We should show $\dfrac{CT}{TB}=\dfrac{CL}{LB}$. How can I use $\angle ACL=\angle BCL=60^\circ$? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observe a triangle $ACL$ and extend halfline $AC$ to $X$.

Notice that $CT$ is outer angle bisector for angle $\angle ACL$ since $\angle LCT = \angle LCX = 60^{\circ}$.

Since $T$ is also on angle bisector $AT$ of angle $\angle CAL$. So $T$ is at equal distance to lines $CL$ and $LB$, so $LT$ is angle bisector of angle $\angle CLB$.

Comment: Can I ask where is the point $X$?

Comment: Wherever on halfline AC beyond C.

Comment: Can it lie on the segment $AC$?

Comment: Better no, C should be between A and X

Comment: Let me get this straight. $CT$ is outer angle bisector for $\angle ACL$ since $\angle LCT=\angle TCX=60^\circ$. Doesn't this mean $T$ is at equal distance to lines $AC$ and $AL$?

Comment: No, to lines AC and CL

Comment: My mistake! Yes, $T$ is at equal distance to lines $AC$ and $CL$. How do we get $T$ is at equal distance to lines $CL$ and $LB$ from here?

Comment: Added a new drawing. Since $TD=TE$ and $TD=TF$, $TE=TE$ so $LT$ is angle bisector of angle $CLB$. Right?

Comment: yeah...............

Answer (score 1):

By the [Law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines),
$$\frac{|AB|}{\sin(120^{\circ})}=\frac{|BC|}{\sin(A)},\quad
\frac{|AL|}{\sin(60^{\circ})}=\frac{|CL|}{\sin(A)}.$$
Since $\sin(120^{\circ})=\sin(60^{\circ})$, it follows that
$$\frac{|AB|}{|BC|}=\frac{|AL|}{|CL|}.$$
Hence, from your work,
$$\frac{|CT|}{|TB|}=\frac{|AC|}{|AB|}=\frac{|AC|}{|BC|}\cdot
\frac{|CL|}{|AL|}=\frac{|AL|}{|LB|}\cdot
\frac{|CL|}{|AL|}=\frac{|CL|}{|LB|}$$
and we are done.

P.S. In order to avoid the Law of sines, note that 
$$|AC||BC|\sin(120^{\circ})=2\text{Area}(ABC)=|AB||AC|\sin(A)$$
implies 
$$\frac{|AB|}{\sin(120^{\circ})}=\frac{|BC|}{\sin(A)}.$$
Similarly, by considering the triangle $ACL$, we find
$$\frac{|AL|}{\sin(60^{\circ})}=\frac{|CL|}{\sin(A)}.$$

Comment: We haven't studied Sine Theorem.

Comment: Please see my edit. I mean the Law of sines

Comment: We haven't studied this either. We have only studied the Angle Bisector theorem.

Comment: Please see my PS